Prove that the intersection of spheres $Sm, Sn$ are circles
let $Sm$ be a sphere of center $Im(m+1,m-1,2)$ and radius $\sqrt{2m^2+9}$ :
prove that all spheres for all $m$ intersect in a circle and determine its center and radius.
i have tried setting the center of the circle to be a part of the line that Im describes. then saying that Imω= $\sqrt{2m^2+9−r}$
with ω/r being the center/radius of the circle respectively. then I said that for Im =ω : $\sqrt{2m^2+9−r}$ = 0 and then I got stuck.
thanks.

Let's do some scratch work. We know that the family of spheres does intersect along a circle because the problem is telling you so. The stupidly obvious thing to do is just to pick two random values for $m$ and see where those spheres intersect. So for a given $m$, the equation of the corresponding sphere is:
$(x-(m+1))^2+(y-(m-1))^2+(z-2)^2=\left(\sqrt{2m^2+9}\right)^2$.
Let's just do something weird like $m=1$ and $m=-1$ because it makes stuff cancel. For $m=1$ we get this sphere:
$(x-2)^2+y^2+(z-2)^2=11,$ (eq 1)
and for $m=-1$ we get this sphere:
$x^2+(y+2)^2+(z-2)^2=11.$ (eq 2)
Now where do these spheres intersect? Well spheres have 3 variables since they're a surface and circles need 2 since they're a curve. So we should suppose that both equations 1 and 2 hold and eliminate either $x$, $y$, or $z$. Equations 1 and 2 suggest:
$(x-2)^2+y^2=x^2+(y+2)^2,$
$x^2-4x+4+y^2=x^2+y^2+4y+4,$
$-4x=4y,$
So this means that the circle of intersection must live in the plane $y=-x$. We can now take either equation 1 or 2 and say $y=-x$. Doing so is just finding the slice of one of the spheres with the plane $y=-x$; the circle from the cross-section is where the intersection ought to happen. Take equation 1 and replace $y$ with $-x$ to get:
$2(x^2-2x+1)+2+(z-2)^2=11,$
$2(x-1)^2+(z-2)^2=3^2,$
and:
$\left(\frac{x}{1/\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}\right)^2+(z-2)^2=3^2.$
Now this looks rather goofy because the coefficient of $\frac{1}{1/\sqrt{2}}$ in front of $x$ means we have an ellipse, not a circle. I was kinda confused so I put it into GeoGebra3D (you should try it too) and realized my mistake. This $x$-$z$ equation is merely the projection of the circle we're actually looking for onto the $x$-$z$ plane. However, we do know that the $x$ coordinate of the circle center is the same as that for this $x$-$z$ ellipse. The center of this ellipse is $(1,2)$. Since $y=-x$, the coordinates of the center in 3D space will be $(1,-1,2)$. The projection only causes distortion in the $x$ direction, but the vertical distance between the top and bottom of the ellipse is the diameter of the original circle. The vertical extrema of the ellipse occurs at $x=1$, where $z$ can be $2\pm3$, meaning the true circle has a radius of 6.
There's probably a more systematic way to do this, but I wanted to post this in case it helped, or can be of help in some way with future problems.
Here's one sphere intersecting $y=-x$ (the circle that's made won't change as you change $m$; go to GeoGebra3D and try it):

And this is the projection of that circle onto the $x$-$z$ plane; viewed sideways it looks more like an ellipse:


@WillJagy I think what's happening may be that you're checking $(3,-1,1)$ lies on one sphere but not the other.

I posted an answer with corrected $(x,y,z)$ points

Consider two spheres $S_m$ and $S_n$ with radii $r_m $ and $r_n $, respectively. WLOG $n>m$. Then the distance between $I_m$ and $I_n$ is $d=(n-m)\sqrt2$.
If the shperes intersect the intersection is a circle with the center on the same line $(t+1,t-1,2)$ which connects $I_m $ and $I_n$, so that the  center of the circle in question has coordinates:
$$\begin{align}
I_C&=(m+1,m-1,2)+\frac{(1,1,0)}{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{d^2+r_m^2-r_n^2}{2d}\\
&=(m+1,m-1,2)+\frac{(1,1,0)}{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{2(n-m)^2+(2m^2+9)-(2n^2+9)}
{2\sqrt2(n-m)}\\
&=(m+1,m-1,2)-m(1,1,0)=(1,-1,2).
\end{align}$$
I left it to you to prove that the radius of the circle is $3$.

 Hint: $$r^2_m-|I_mI_C|^2=(2m^2+9)-2m^2$$


oof this is really complex for me. thanks for the answer

Nothing complex, just consider triangle with sides $d, r_m,r_n$. :)

Are $r_m$ and $r_n$ the radii of $S_m$ and $S_n$?

Yes, they are...

The equation of each $S_m$ is given by
$$
(x-m-1)^2 + (y-m+1)^2 + (z-2)^2 = 2m^2+9.
$$
If we put $u=x-1,\,v=y+1$ and $w=z-2$, the equations of $S_m$ and $S_n$ in the $uvw$ coordinate frame are given by
\begin{align}
(u-m)^2 + (v-m)^2 + w^2 &= 2m^2+9,\tag{1}\\
(u-n)^2 + (v-n)^2 + w^2 &= 2n^2+9.\tag{2}\\
\end{align}
When $m\ne n$, we obtain from $(1)-(2)$ the following equation:
$$
\left[-2u(m-n)+m^2-n^2\right]+\left[-2v(m-n)+m^2-n^2\right] = 2(m^2-n^2).
$$
This simplifies to $u+v=0$, i.e.,
$$
v=-u.\tag{3}
$$
Substitute this back into $(1)$, we obtain
\begin{align}
(u-m)^2 + (-u-m)^2 + w^2 &= 2m^2+9,\\
(u-m)^2 + (u+m)^2 + w^2 &= 2m^2+9,\\
2u^2 + w^2 &= 9,\\
u^2 + v^2 + w^2 &= 9.\tag{4}\\
\end{align}
This shows that when $m\ne n$, the intersection of $S_m$ and $S_n$ in the $uvw$-space is precisely the intersection of the plane $P:v=-u$ and the sphere $S:u^2+v^2+w^2=9$ centred at the origin (of the $uvw$-space) of radius $3$. Since $P$ and $S$ do not depend on $m$ and $n$, we conclude that their intersection is the intersection of all spheres $S_m$ for $m=1,2,\ldots$.
While intuitively obvious, we still need to prove that the intersection of $P$ and $S$ is indeed a circle. To this end, let
$$
u'=\frac{u-v}{\sqrt{2}}\quad\text{and}\quad v'=\frac{u+v}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$
By $(3)$, it is now clear that the intersection of $P$ and $S$ lies entirely inside the $u'w$-plane
$$
v'=0
$$
and hence by $(4)$ (note that $(u')^2+(v')^2=u^2+v^2$), its locus in the $u'v'w$-space is that of the circle
$$
(u')^2+w^2=9
$$
centred at the origin with radius $3$. Since the $u'v'w$ coordinate frame is obtained by a 45-degree anticlockwise rotation of the $uvw$ coordinate frame about the $w$-axis, and the $xyz$ coordinate frame is a translation of the $uvw$ coordinate frame, we conclude that the intersection of $P$ and $S$ is also a circle of radius $3$ in the $xyz$-space. The centre of the circle is the origin in the $uvw$-space or the $u'v'w$-space, i.e., $(1,-1,2)$ in the $xyz$-space.

Each center is $\sqrt{2 m^2 + 6} $   from the origin. With radius $\sqrt{2 m^2 + 9}, $   each sphere passes fairly close to the origin. Thus, it made sense to find constant points near the origin that would be on every sphere.
Fiddling, some of my errors in comments below Pineapple Fish's  answer.
Finally, I found four correct points on every sphere,
$$   (-1,1,1) \; , \; \; \; (-1,1,3)  \; , \; \; \;  (3,-3,1)   \; , \; \; \;  (3,-3,3)  $$
all using the identity  $(m+2)^2 + ( m-2)^2 + 1^2 = 2 m^2 +9  .$
Other integer points include $(1,-1,5)$  and $(1,-1,-1).$
Those four points are, indeed, in the plane $x+y = 0.$ Next, they are vertices of a rectangle   with center $(1,-1,2) $   The radius turns out to be $3.$
A parametrization of the circle is then
$$  (1,-1,2)  + 3 \cos t \; \; (0,0,1) + 3 \sin t \; \; (\frac{-1}{\sqrt 2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} ,0)  $$
Going counterclockwise (increasing $t$ ), the integer points appear in order
$$ (1,-1,5) \; , \; \;  (-1,1,3) \; , \; \;  (-1,1,1) \; , \; \;  (1,-1,-1) \; , \; \;  (3,-3,1) \; , \; \;  (3,-3,3) \; ;; \; \; (1,-1,5)  $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
I printed out points  and calculated the squared distance to the sphere center for $m=2$   and then for $m=3$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Given the spheres:



$\textbf{m}$
Centre
Radius




$-1$
$I_{-1} = (0,-2,2)$
$\sqrt{11}$


$0$
$I_{0} = (1,-1,2)$
$3$


$+1$
$I_{+1} = (2,0,2)$
$\sqrt{11}$



You can define an isosceles triangle with corners at $I_{-1}$, $I_{+1}$ and a  third point $\sqrt{11}$ (the radius of the two spheres) away from both of those two points. The set of points for this third point of the isosceles triangle is the points of intersection of the two spheres and defines a circle around $I_{0}$, the midpoint between $I_{-1}$ and $I_{+1}$, and has the same radius as $S_{0}$.
Therefore, the centre of the circle where the spheres intersect is $(1,-1,2)$ and the radius is $3$.
A graphical representation showing the isosceles triangle created by the intersection of the spheres from $S_{-1}$, $S_{0}$ and $S_{+1}$ in the plane $Z=2$:

To prove that the spheres all intersect the same circle then we can use Pythagoras theorem:
Given an isosceles triangle with the corners $I_{-m}$, $I_{+m}$ and the point of intersection, $P$, of the spheres with radius $\sqrt{2 m^2 + 9}$ from those points then there is a right-angled triangle with the corner $I_{0}$, the mid-point between $I_{-m}$ and $I_{+m}$.

The distance from $I_{-m}$ to $I_{+m}$ is $2\sqrt{2} m$ and from each to $I_{0}$ is half that, $\sqrt{2} m$.

The radius of $S_{-m}$ and $S_{+m}$ are both $\sqrt{2 m^2 + 9}$.

Using Pythagoras theorem:
$$\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
   |\vec{I_{m}P}|^2 &= |\vec{I_{m}I_{0}}|^2 + |\vec{I_{0}P}|^2 \\
   (\sqrt{2 m^2 + 9})^2 &= (\sqrt{2} m)^2 + |\vec{I_{0}P}|^2 \\
   3 &= |\vec{I_{0}P}|
   \end{aligned}
   \end{equation}$$
So the circle defined by the intersection of the spheres $S_{-m}$ and $S_{+m}$ will always have a radius of 3 for all $m$. Given that this is independent of $m$ then any sphere $S_{m}$ and $S_{n}$ will also intersect in the same constant radius $3$ circle with centre $I_{0}$.


